# How to insert row in array based on value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im using this formula to create array:

`= SORT( (FILTER( { (Details)\(Emails)\(INT(Timestamp))\(Note)} ; (Attending="Yes"))) ; 7 ; True)`

Details, Emails, Timestamp, Note, Attending are all named ranges from different sheet.

Timestamp column is date format.

Is there a way to split array where new date value appears?

Lets say timestamp in arrray is in column 'G' and G2:G7 is 8/16/2022 and G8:G20 is 8/17/2022

I would like to have row or some kind of indicator in between.

Comment: How about just using conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the results of your `sort()` formula are in the range `sort!A2:G`, and you want to insert a blank row every time the value in column `sort!F2:F` changes, put this formula in cell `A2` of a blank sheet:

```
=arrayformula( iferror( 
  vlookup( 
    sort( 
      { 
        filter(row(sort!F2:F); len(sort!F2:F)); 
        filter(row(sort!F2:F); len(sort!F2:F); sort!F2:F <> sort!F3:F) + 0,3 
      } 
    ); 
    { row(sort!F2:F) \ sort!A2:G }; 
    column(sort!A2:G) - column(sort!A2) + 2; 
    false 
  ) 
) )
```

Format column `F` as **Format > Number > Date**.

The formula uses separators that work in locales that use comma as decimal mark. To make it work in a locale that uses period as decimal mark, replace the comma there with a period, all semicolons with commas except the one following the first `filter()`, and the backslash `\` with a comma.

This is a well-known pattern to insert a blank row between rows where the value in a key column changes (here, column `F`). For an explanation of how it works, see [Insert blank row after every group for same data](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/85285070).

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including a brief explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Edited the answer to include a link to an explanation. It is a well-known pattern that has been in use for [several years](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4205954).

Comment: @doubleunary Here is the link of sample, which is similar to what i use rn. There is also a sheet named 'Goal' where you can see what i'd like to acomplish (dont mind colors there) 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xsw9A1K3fNALwXixJE2na7QKYV9TcEZGnSOi2CB6fng/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Edited the answer to match your sample spreadsheet.

Comment: @doubleunary Thanks for help, it works perfectly.

Is there a way to insert date in those blank rows :)

As of StackExchange, yea i am new so i cant Vote Up your answer so i marked it :)

Comment: That is a different question that will require a different solution. Please post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).