# How to insert date in blank row inside of array

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have this formula that reorganizes my starting array by inserting blank rows where new date value appears.

```
=arrayformula( iferror( 
  vlookup( 
    sort( 
      { 
        filter(row(sort!F2:F); len(sort!F2:F)); 
        filter(row(sort!F2:F); len(sort!F2:F); sort!F2:F <> sort!F3:F) + 0,3 
      } 
    ); 
    { row(sort!F2:F) \ sort!A2:G }; 
    column(sort!A2:G) - column(sort!A2) + 2; 
    false 
  ) 
) )
```

(from [How to insert row in array based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73911883/13045193))

The results of the above formula look like this:

| Name | LastName | Jobtitle | Company | Email | Timestamp | Note2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name 3 | LastName3 | Title3 | Company3 | Email@3.com | 30.06.2022. | RANDOM NOTE 3 |
| Name5 | LastName5 | Title5 | Company5 | Email@5.com | 30.06.2022. | RANDOM NOTE 5 |
| Name7 | LastName7 | Title7 | Company7 | Email@7.com | 30.06.2022. | RANDOM NOTE 7 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Name89 | LastName89 | Title89 | Company89 | Email@89.com | 06.07.2022. | RANDOM NOTE 89 |
| Name90 | LastName90 | Title90 | Company90 | Email@90.com | 06.07.2022. | RANDOM NOTE 90 |
| Name91 | LastName91 | Title91 | Company91 | Email@91.com | 06.07.2022. | RANDOM NOTE 91 |
| Name92 | LastName92 | Title92 | Company92 | Email@92.com | 06.07.2022. | RANDOM NOTE 92 |
| Name94 | LastName94 | Title94 | Company94 | Email@94.com | 06.07.2022. | RANDOM NOTE 94 |
| Name95 | LastName95 | Title95 | Company95 | Email@95.com | 06.07.2022. | RANDOM NOTE 95 |
| Name97 | LastName97 | Title97 | Company97 | Email@97.com | 06.07.2022. | RANDOM NOTE 97 |
| Name98 | LastName98 | Title98 | Company98 | Email@98.com | 06.07.2022. | RANDOM NOTE 98 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Name99 | LastName99 | Title99 | Company99 | Email@99.com | 07.07.2022. | RANDOM NOTE 99 |

How do I insert a date in the `Note2` column in each blank row? The date should come from the `Timestamp` column in the following row.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xsw9A1K3fNALwXixJE2na7QKYV9TcEZGnSOi2CB6fng/edit?usp=sharing) is the sample sheet where you can see the idea (Goal Sheet).

Comment: It looks like you copied this code from somewhere else. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, you can [edit], include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, mention the author's name, and [quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**plain text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to the question. Adding such "markdown tables" greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert dates in the `Note2` column `G` by copying the data in the `Cleaner way` sheet conditionally, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    isblank('Cleaner way'!G1:G500); 
    { 'Cleaner way'!A1:F500 \ 'Cleaner way'!F2:F501 }; 
    'Cleaner way'!A1:G500 
  ) 
)
```

The `{}` bit is an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276).

You did not ask for it, but since the separator rows are highlighted in the [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xsw9A1K3fNALwXixJE2na7QKYV9TcEZGnSOi2CB6fng/edit#gid=991251939), you may want to use a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule to do the same automatically. See the Solution sheet in your sample spreadsheet.